# The sequence $x^{(k)}=(x_1,x_2,..x_k,0,...) \in \ell_1 $ converges to x

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Given any (fixed) element $x\in \ell_1$, show that the sequence $x^{(k)} = (x_1, x_2 ,..., x_k,0,0...)\in \ell_1$ converges to x in $\ell_1$-norm.

Note the $\ell_1$-norm is: $\|x_n\|_1 = \sum |x_i-x|$

Also, note that $\forall x \in \ell_p : \|x\|_p < \infty$

---

Any tips? I am really not sure how to even approach this problem besides the fact that I'll use the definition of a limit.

Comment: What's the set $l_1$ you're referring to?

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of limit? What does the sequence $\|x-x^{(k)}\|_1$ tend to?

Comment: @David $l_1$ is a standard notation for the set of infinite sequences of real (or complex) numbers whose sum converges absolutely, equipped with the norm given by the same absolute sum. More common is the related $l_2$, using the Euclidean norm.

Comment: Yes I used the definition but I can't find something that it would be smaller from. I think I don't really understand how || x-x^{(k)} || would even  look like

Comment: @Sofia Then take a concrete example or two, like $x=(1,1/4,\ldots,1/n^2,\ldots)$ or $x=(1/2,1/4,\ldots,1/2^n, \ldots)$, and see what $x^{(k)}$ and $\|x-x^{(k)}\|_1$ are in that case. I usually find that concrete examples help me understand things like this.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** $$||x-x^{(n)}||_1 = \sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} |x_k|$$

is the rest of a convergent series.